# I can't figure out how to setup nodes based on YT comment for bloom with a transparent background

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I have some object which uses bloom in Eevee and as you know I can't save render result with transparent background, so I found this YT video in which the author figure out how to set it up for export with two image sequences but he had shown how to combine them in Blender. He showed how to combine them in a painting program. Here is the link to the YT video https://youtu.be/tmb5HRU1cUo?t=698. And here is pinned YT comment from which I'm trying to reconstruct the node setup.

> To do this without rendering twice, just set up a separate *File Output*
> node in the compositor and feed the *Alpha* channel into it. Uncheck
> *'Use alpha'* in the main composite node. Then you'll get both separate
> files in one render process. Then just invert the alpha pass in your
> compositing app to make it black-on-transparent and use this method.
> This resulted in some white fringe so then just set the inverted alpha
> layer to *Multiply*.

Here is the original node setup:

[image: Original]

Here is my try:

[image: Node-setup]

but I'm missing some parts from that comment. I can't figure out this part:

> This resulted in some white fringe so then just set the inverted alpha
> layer to *Multiply*.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean you can’t save the render results with a transparent background? I do it all the time, and bloom isn’t lost.

Comment: @TheLabCat yes but did you tried to save it if you use bloom in your scene ?

Comment: I stand corrected. Bloom is lost. It shows up in the render result, however, so I think this is a bug.

Comment: Ah, no it isn't, it's a problem with the PNG format. https://developer.blender.org/T81199 See the last comment here. Let me just double-check with OpenEXR...

Comment: Hmm, OpenEXR doesn't store it either...

Comment: @TheLabCat no it's not a bug take a look at YT video which I mentioned in my question